# How to see JLabel Array in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

This is my click action:

```
  succ.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                int x=0;
                int i;
               labelpanel.revalidate();
               labelpanel.repaint();
            for (i=status; i<status+5; i++){

                RidimIcon locand = new RidimIcon();
                labelapp.get(i).setBounds(74+x, 1, 80, 90);

                labelapp.get(i).setIcon(locand.newicona(pathicon[i], labelapp.get(i)));
                labelpanel.add(labelapp.get(i));

                    x=x+120;
               }
                status=status+5; //change status
            }

         });
```

"Labelpanel" is an array of JLabel:

```
    try {
        ResultSet rs = Datainter.eseguiQuery(query);
        while(rs.next())
        {

            pathicon[contatore] = rs.getString("locandina");

            JLabel tmplabel = new JLabel();
            labelapp.add(tmplabel);

            labelapp.get(contatore).setIcon(new ImageIcon(pathicon[contatore]));
            contatore++;

        }


    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

i want to create programm that see 5 image at click. I have an array labels with 50 images, when i click first time i see 1 - 5 labels[1-5], when i click second time i see labels[5-10], third time [10-11] etc..
Why i see only first 5 labelapp when i click on "succ"?
How can i see other 5 labelapp when i click again and leave first 5 images in panel?

(with RemoveAll i cant see my last Jlabels:

```
             prec.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                int x=0;
                int i;
                    labelpanel.removeAll();
                        for (i=status; i<status-5; i--){

                            RidimIcon locand = new RidimIcon();
                            labelapp.get(i).setBounds(74+x, 1, 80, 90);
                            labelapp.get(i).setIcon(locand.newicona(pathicon[i], labelapp.get(i)));
                            labelpanel.add(labelapp.get(i));

                                x=x+120;

                        }
                        labelpanel.revalidate();
                        labelpanel.repaint();

                        status=status-5;
            } 
        });
```

Comment: What is `status` value? Where do you change it?

Comment: status is `private int status=0;` .. when i click `succ` status=5 (i see first 5 image), when i click again status=10 (i see 5 to 10 i-images)..  I change it when close For (`status=status+5;`)

Comment: Do you want to see 10 labels after double click? Or only the last 5 labels?

Comment: Likely you'll have a much easier time if you simply use a JList, one that displays ImageIcons, and not try to use a bunch of JLabels. You certainly don't want to use null layouts and `setBounds` as it appears that you're doing. If you want to get better answers though, please give us a better understanding of your problem by creating and posting a valid [mcve] -- please read the link!

Comment: @ReşitDönük I want to see other 5 Labels when i click with mouse, not ALL labels.. i want to create programm that see 5 image at click. I have an array labels with 50 images, when i click first time i see 1 - 5 labels[1-5], when i click second time i see labels[5-10], third time [10-11] etc..

Comment: I use java from 2 weeks, sorry for my ignorance

Comment: Don't apologize, but instead (and again) consider creating and posting your [mcve]. That would be time much better spent.

Answer (score 1):

Use `removeAll()` to remove all previous labels from the `labelPanel`. Then add new labels and call `revalidate()` and `repaint()`.

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
     int x=0;
     int i;

     labelpanel.removeAll();
     for (i=status; i<status+5; i++){

         RidimIcon locand = new RidimIcon();
         labelapp.get(i).setBounds(74+x, 1, 80, 90);

         labelapp.get(i).setIcon(locand.newicona(pathicon[i], labelapp.get(i)));
         labelpanel.add(labelapp.get(i));

         x=x+120;
      }

      labelpanel.revalidate();
      labelpanel.repaint();

      status=status+5; //change status
      if(status > 17) {
          status = 17;
      }
}
```

And some advices;

- Use naming [conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html).
- Do not use null layout. [why-is-it-frowned-upon-to-use-a-null-layout-in-swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592468/why-is-it-frowned-upon-to-use-a-null-layout-in-swing)

Comment: But now, if i use removeAll() i cant see my last jlabels:

Comment: You see the first ones or nothing?

Comment: And do you move the revalidate and repaint to the proper position as in my answer?

Comment: see my edit code, i need label `prec` to see last image.. exemple= when i click succ i see JLabels[10-15], when i click prec i wanna see [5-10]

Comment: with RemoveAll() i see what i wanna to see..is perfect..but i have other mouse event to another label that i use too see 
Previous 5 images (with 'prec', i insert it on my question)

Comment: Condition in for loop is wrong. `i<status-5` should be `i>=status-5`. And assignment part must be `i=status-1`.

Comment: So, your for loop must be like this `for (i=status-1; i>=status-5; i--)`

Comment: I have another problem D: I have 17 image but when my for go to (i=15, i <20) give me an error: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException .. how can i resolve this?

Comment: If you have 17 images index must be maximum 16. So check if status bigger than 17. See my updated code.

Comment: Don't work D: but not ever status>17, depends from my database images.. i need an If that can resolve this nullPionterException

Comment: can i tell u new question?  ` Color c=new Color(200,0,0,100);
                    labelpanel.setBackground(c);
                    labelpanel.setOpaque(true); ` Where can i put it in my mouse event? when i click on Prec or Succ this code dont work

Comment: If you put this code before repaint() it should work, I think.

Comment: "more and more red" interesting! It is hard to find problem without seeing all application. May be you should ask another question for this situation.

Comment: can i have a chat with u? or with teamviewer or something

Comment: Maybe calling revalidate and repaint from your main panel fix your issue. (main panel is the panel which holds labelPanel)

Comment: Where? Under labelpanel.repaint() i write contentPane.revalidate and repaint? (Like your comment code)

Comment: Yeap, give it a try.